# Infinite intersection of nested finite open cover of a compact space

Tags: general-topology

In my research, $X$ is a topological space and for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\mathcal{U}_n$ is a finite open cover of $X$ such that for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we have $\mathcal{U}_{n+1}\prec \mathcal{U}_n$. This means that for every $A\in\mathcal{U}_{n+1}$, there is $B\in\mathcal{U}_n$ with $A\subseteq B$. Also we assume that $\mathcal{U}_m\neq \mathcal{U}_n$ for every $n\neq m\in\mathbb{N}$.

Consider infinite sequences $\{x_n\}, \{y_n\}\subseteq X$ such that  $x_n\to x$, $y_n\to y$ and $\{x_n, y_n\}\prec\mathcal{U}_n$.

What  conditions on $X$ implies that  $x=y$?

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that you can find reasonble conditions on $X$. As an example take a space $X$ having infinitely many open subsets. Pick a sequence $U_1 = X, U_2, U_3, \dots$ of distinct open sets and define $\mathcal U_n = \{U_1,\dots , U_n \}$. Then clearly $\mathcal{U}_{n+1}\prec \mathcal{U}_n$ since each $U_i \in \mathcal{U}_{n+1}$ is contained in $U_1  \in \mathcal{U}_{n}$. By definition $\mathcal{U}_m\neq \mathcal{U}_n$ for every $n\neq m\in\mathbb{N}$.

Now pick any two distinct $x,y \in X$ and define $x_n = x, y_n = y$. Then $x_n \to x, y_n \to y$ and $\{ x_n, y_n \} = \{x, y\} \subset U_1 \in \mathcal{U}_{n}$.

The only chance to get a positive result is to impose restrictions on $X$ **and** on the $\mathcal{U}_{n}$.